# From non-linear homogeneous DAE to linear state-space form

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems, nonlinear

I have a non-linear homogeneous DAE $x' = F(y)$, $G(y) = 0$ where $x$, $y$ are vectors, $F$ is linear with constant coefficients, and $G$ is a polynomial with parametric coefficients.

How can I transform it into linear state-space form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StateSpaceModel[Flatten@{x'[t]==F[y[t]], G[y[t]]==0},  
Flatten@{x[t],y[t]}, {}, Flatten@{x[t],y[t]}, t]
```

where $t$ is the independent variable.

For a concrete example see the documentation [[link]](http://wolfram.com/xid/0v5g4hmcblbdp-dwsl2k).

Comment: Ah good old `Flatten` -- one of my favorites. :)